# bring data from table

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, react-native

I have a file called `index.js` it contain the query to select data from my table.

In another file I have written code to bring data from my table. When I execute the code I can print some words but I can't print or bring data from the table.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            employees:[],
            success : 0
        }
        this.getList = this.getList.bind(this)

    }
    getList(){
        let config = {
            url:'/api/gettable '
        };
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            customFetch(config)
            .then((res) => {
                resolve(res.rows);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(new Error(err));
            });
        })
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        try{
            let employeeData = await this.getList();
            this.setState({
                employees:employeeData
            })
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="dashboard animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3 ">
                 <div className="row">
                    <div className="app-wrapper pb-0">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Welcom</h1>



                            {this.state.employees.map(employee => <div>Id={employee.Id} Name={employee.Name} Description={employee.Description} Date={employee.Date} </div>)}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        );
    }

}

export default MyApp ;
```

It prints `welcome`  but didn't print the data of table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Change this line

```
this.state.employees.map(employee => <div>Id={employee.Id} Name={employee.Name} Description={employee.Description} Date={employee.Date} </div>)}
```

To

```
 {this.state.employees && this.state.employees.map(employee => <div>Id={employee.Id} Name={employee.Name} Description={employee.Description} Date={employee.Date} </div>)}
```

Comment: console it employeeData in componentDidMount, make sure data is getting or not.
debug step by step